# Use of preposition у in questions about the magnitude of a quantity

Tags: предлоги

Today, Duolingo taught me that it's *Какая глубина этого озера?*, but *Какая ширина у этой улицы?*. My questions are

1. Is that a case of binary grammaticality? I. e., would *Какая глубина у этого озера?* or *Какая ширина этой улицы?* be ungrammatical or unusual?
2. If yes, is either of these cases an exception? That is, do/don't you usually use *у* with physical quantities? If no, is there a rule or can you give me a table relating common quantities to their use of *у*?
3. What about more "technical" quantities, such as density, potential, or flux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No, either way is correct (in either case), and I even struggle to say which one is more common.
2. I'd say that usually we *don't* use *y* with physical quantities (or qualities); plain Genitive is the 'default' way applicable to everything. *Площадь кухни, плотность свинца, возраст дочери, напряжение обмотки, цвет стены.* So the basic rule is simple: if in doubt, don't use *y*.
3. As above, generally without *y*. Having the preposition makes the phrase slightly less formal (or so it feels to me), and technical/formal writing avoids it.

Comment: Some orderings of words do require the preposition. *Какая ёмкость [у] этой цистерны? Какая у этой цистерны ёмкость?*

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, in combination with the question word **какой(-ая)** in your examples, *omitting* the preposition **у** sounds a bit unusual if not awkward.  Probably, it's because the question is about *assigning* a value to an object (like, *what* depth/width *value* it *has*). You don't need a preposition with another question word, **каков(а)**, since the question would focus on the *value* only (*how much* its width value is):

> **Какова** ширина этой улицы? 
> **Какова** глубина этого озера?

2. A possible context with the question word **какая** but without need for **у** (as above, *value* is in focus):

> **Какая** глубина этого озера сделала бы его судоходным?
>   **Какая** ширина этой улицы могла бы исключить пробки?

3. In formal cases (scientific or engineering writings) preposition **у** is *avoided* (except when it means *near*), so the question word is selected so that it provides focusing on *value*:

> **Какова** скорость света в полипропилене?
>  **Какая** температура плавления
>   этого сплава обеспечит заданные характеристики объекта?

Comment: Also compare with: "Какой ширины эта улица?"